# Yelp API to support write review for business page

Tags: php, javascript, yelp

Does Yelp provide API support to write reviews on business page? Is there any way to write reviews from another site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it is unlikely that there ever will be.

*Full disclosure: I worked for Yelp for over 2 years.*

Comment: I knew that yelp had not provided support in 2010-2011 but was not sure about API v 2.0. thank you ... :)

Comment: I want to get the string yelp passing in write review page URL. How can I get that? I want to show that URL only so user click on that url and directly go to that page for write a review.

Answer (score 0):

So, Yelp still does not provide the API for reviews from other sites. There is a way to write reviews from your site. Just make an internal iframe pointing to your yelp reviews.

The easiest way to just link to the review page of the business.

1. Find the business on Yelp.
2. Click on Write a Review next to the business name. (It will take you to the actual page to write a review).
3. Now just copy and use the url to create a call out link on your website.

That's it.